# vue - inserting rows and columns into a table with scoped css

Tags: html, vue.js, html-table, vuejs2

So I'm trying to insert rows and columns into a table using the code below:

```
add_to_table(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case "row":
      let columns = this.$refs.table.rows[0].cells.length;
      let row = this.$refs.table.insertRow(-1);
      row.height = "20px";
      for (let i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
      }
      break;
    case "column":
      for (let row of this.$refs.table.rows) {
        let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to maintain the css (doesn't add the `data-*` stuff to it).

I'm currently working around this by using `v-for`:

```
<tr v-for="row in rows">    
    <td v-for="column in columns">
    </td>    
</tr>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/8n728r5wr8

Comment: Why are you resorting to manipulating the DOM (`.innerHTML` and such)? The `v-for` solution is the way to go.

Comment: @acdcjunior might want to add cells to an individual row. This only allows for equal rows and columns. Also not sure how to do stuff like `colSpan` .

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but it could be done using Vue much simpler.

Comment: @acdcjunior which is why I'm asking. I'm looking to apply `colSpan` `rowSpan` and maybe other things which may result in unequal cells.

Comment: Can you show us the data (you plan to iterate on) so we can give it a shot using Vue? I know it seems manipulating the DOM is simpler, but I guarantee you the end result using Vue will be much better.

Comment: @acdcjunior Well there isn't really any data. It's kinda a bit like excel. So I'm planning to have the table to be able to create rows/columns then be able to "merge" cells together after selecting some of them by clicking on them, then hitting a "merge" button. Which is why I would need to delete some cells after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your created rows and columns are not getting styled because the `<style>` you declared is `scoped`.

For the elements to get the scoped style, they must have a `data-v-SOMETHING` attribute. The elements you create manually, not via Vue, don't have that attribute.

> **WARNING**: Vue is data-driven, the correct, simplest, more predictable
>   and maintainable way of achieving what you want is mutating a `data`
>   attribute and letting Vue's templates react to it accordingly (using
>   directives like `v-for`). Your solution is not optimal. You have been warned.

That being said, you have some options:

- Declare an additional `<style>` (non-`scoped`) tag along the `scoped` one. The created elements will pick up these styles. **Drawback:** the styles will be global. **Advantage:** you don't depend on Vue internals, you don't have to always add the `data-v` attribute (see below).

  Example:

  ```
  <style scoped>
  ...
  </style>
  <style>
  /* EXAMPLE OF GLOBAL STYLE ALONGSIDE A SCOPED ONE */
  tr, td {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px orange;
  }
  </style>
  ```
- Get a hold of the `data-v-SOMETHING` attribute. It is available at `this.$options._scopeId`. **Double Warning**: the prefix `_` means it is [internal code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4218#issuecomment-260972860). It may change without notice. Your app may be forever stuck with the current Vue 2.x versions. You have been warned again.

  So, whenever you create elements, just add the attribute. Example:

  ```js
  // row example
  let row = this.$refs.table.insertRow(-1);
  row.setAttribute(this.$options._scopeId, ""); // <== this adds the data-v-XYZ attr
  ...
  // cell example
  let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
  cell.setAttribute(this.$options._scopeId, ""); // <== this adds the data-v-XYZ attr
  ```

[**Here's a CodeSandbox demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl99xj39qw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue) containing examples for both alternatives.